# Add SQLite function with Android architecture components

Tags: android, sqlite, android-architecture-components, custom-function

I've implemented various distance and bearing functionality between GPS coordinates in iOS using `sqlite3_create_function`. Porting it to Android I've started to look at the Android architecture components such as `Room` and was wondering if there was a way to use sqlite functions in this?

I've seen references to using the NDK and write them in C/C++ but I was wondering whether the architecture components had addressed sqlite functions in Java.

Or perhaps it would be better to move the functionality outside the database but it would mean tricky searching for nearby points in a certain direction.